# gRPC Error 13 when sending float array from Python to Node.js

Tags: python, arrays, node.js, grpc, dataformat

Everything works fine with string arrays, or individual floats. When I try to do:

```
message FeatureListResponse {
  string message = 1;
  repeated float feature_vector = 4;
}
```

I get:

```
{ Error at /usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/client.js:505:17 code: 13, metadata: undefined }
```

On the Node.js side -- no errors on the python side. I'm not really sure how to even debug this? I could send my floats as strings if I really had to but that is less than ideal. The gRPC docs say

> ... If you see one of these errors, something is very broken.

Regarding code 13, but I don't really find that helpful.

How can I debug this? Or is it obvious what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a symptom of a bug in Protobuf.js (specifically, [issue #432](https://github.com/dcodeIO/protobuf.js/issues/432)). The simplest way to fix it is to set the `packed` option on the repeated field, as that issue demonstrates. It's OK to set it to either `true` or `false`, as long as it's the same on the client and the server.